# SEO duplicate content issue with alternative URLs

Tags: php, seo, web-config

I have a PHP website where every page can be accessed either by page ID or by page name:

```
http://domain/page_id=ID
http://domain/page=NAME
```

The problem is that Google treats this as duplicated content. What is the best practice to avoid duplicate content in the case? Will 303 redirect will be better than entirely avoiding two different URLs to lead to the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en):

> In the world of content management and online shopping systems, it's
>   common for the same content to be accessed through multiple URLs.

Therefore,

> **Indicate the preferred URL with the rel="canonical" link element**
>
> Suppose you want
>   http://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome/ to be the
>   preferred URL, even though a variety of URLs can access this content.
>   You can indicate this to search engines as follows:
>
> Mark up the canonical page and any other variants with a
>   rel="canonical" link element. Add a  element with the attribute
>   rel="canonical" to the  section of these pages:  
>   This indicates the preferred URL to use to access the green dress
>   post, so that the search results will be more likely to show users
>   that URL structure. (Note: We attempt to respect this, but cannot
>   guarantee this in all cases.)

So, all you need to do is to add the canonical link element to the `<head>` section of your pages with absolute paths.

Comment: The links can be outside the site. The question was how to handle them. I have only one page with this content. From inside the site I link the pages only by name. But from outside the links can be in two ways as explained.

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov To handle duplicate content issues follow my answer above. Now, in case you want the link juice to be aggregated on the original page (a different problem altogether) then you can always 301 redirect all the different versions of your original URL to the original/desired URL.

Comment: Just to clarify. I have a web page that can be access with several alternative URLs:
http://domain/page_id=ID    
http://domain/page=NAME   
http://domain/NAME   
Where I have to put the:
<link rel="canonical" href="canonical_URL" />
and which URL should I use for canonical? Which I prefer the most?

Comment: You need to put the <link rel="canonical" href="your_preferred_URL" /> in all the canonical pages and any other variant pages. This way you will be telling the search engine bots that the particular URL should preferably be accessed through the "your_preferred_URL" only. For more info, refer this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov Please don't forget to accept my answer if its helpful. You can accept my answer by clicking the tick on the left.

Comment: I have added  <link rel="canonical" href="your_preferred_URL" /> to the page (it is only one, the URLs are several) and unfortunately Google still treats the pages as duplicate title and meta description.

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov It will take some considerable time for Google to delete the variants of the URL from its index.

Comment: Some sources claim that the <link rel="canonical" href="your_preferred_URL" /> have to be included only in the non-canonical pages of the website.

Comment: @NikolaObreshkov No you can add it on the canonical page as well. For reference read the heading "Should a page have a self referencing canonical?" here: https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/